# Стоит ли скрывать количество цифр в числе d в алгоритме RSA

Tags: rsa, decrypt

Сгенерировал параметры для rsa шифрования с помощью функции в модуле `rsa` в python.

```
rsa.newkeys(2048)
```

В приватном ключе у меня есть числа n, e и d.

Меня интересует, опасно ли раскрывать количество цифр в числе d, если это всё равно большое число и перебрать будет, я думаю, очень сложно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имеем формулу вычисления `d`:

[image: formula1]

Стандартные библиотеки обычно берут `e=65537`, `φ` почти равно `n`. Итого получается, что минимально возможное `d = φ / 65537`.

Если `d` будет еще меньше, тогда будет справедливо неравество:

[image: formula2]

Это значит что:

[image: formula3]

Остаток от деления никак не станет 1.

При длине ключа 2048 бит минимально возможное `d` будет иметь длину `2048 - 16 = 2032` бит, что очень много. Получается, `d` всегда будет очень большим, и вроде как проблемы нет.

Но, распишем первое равенство по-другому:

[image: formula4]

Если вдруг получится, `c = 1`, тогда `d` получится минимально возможным. Выдавая длину `d` в битах, злоумышленник поймет, что `c = 1` (ведь длина `φ` равна длине `n`). В него не будет значения `φ`, но он знает, что `φ = (p - 1)(q - 1) = n - p - q + 1`. Он знает длину `p` и `q` (1024 бита каждое), и может прикинуть `φ` с точностью до первых 1024 бит. Имея первые 1024 бита `φ` он разделит их на `e` и получит первые 1024 бита `d` (из 2032). Что уже плохо.

Comment: Тогда, чтобы не скрывать длину числа `d`, можно взять ключ длинной 4096 бита?

Comment: У вас какая-то проблема в коде, как так получается, что вы выдаете длину `d`? Никто так не делает. Но если прям нужно, можете просто проверить, что длина `d` равна длине `n`. Если нет, генерируйте другой ключ.

Comment: мне не надо `d` определенной длины. Я зашифровал текст, и думаю, стоит ли мне публиковать количество цифр в числе `d`. Зашифровал RSA2048, и после ваших слов, понял, что не стоит. Теперь, чисто из интереса, интересуюсь, что надо сделать, чтобы публикация длины `d` была безопасна для раскрытия смысла зашифрованного текста.

Comment: С развитием технологий на текущей момент, я думаю, что знание половины `d` ничего не даст при длине ключа 2048.